# knowing what elements of a list view are currently displayed on screen

Tags: android, android-listview

I would know if there is a way to know if an element of a list view gets out of the list, (i want to know if the fist element is seen on screen or isn't)

in fact what I want to do with that, is that i want the second element of my list (which is the title of the fragment where the list is) to stay blocked as a header when it goes up (like an letter in the contact app).
So what i thought about is to add a hidden clone of the second element above the listview (in the relative layout parent), and set it to visible when the first element goes away of the screen (when the second element is the first element of the seen list).

But maybe is it a native way to do so !

Thanks,

Renaud

Comment: you can check for null. If its null then it is not visible which means its view is recylced. so only when it comes back on the screen it is re created

Comment: unfortunatly the view isn't recycled when it goes out the screen, but where it's far from the screen in order to get background loading of the views

Comment: i've got a list adapter of course, but get view is called not at the same time between 2 devices, i can't trust the fact that if my activity inflates the Xth element, it means on my phone that the first one just got away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the first and last visible position in the list at any time using the methods `getFirstVisiblePosition()` and `getLastVisiblePosition()` on `ListView`

HTH